# R cannot be resolved - error and also layout in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

here is the coding

```
package com.st.accounts;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class AddAccount extends Activity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.addaccount);// error occurs here r is not resolved
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return Utils.inflateMenu(this,menu);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return  Utils.handleMenuOption(this,item);
    }

  public void addAccount(View v) {
        // get access to views
        EditText editAcno = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editAcno);
        EditText editCno = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editCno);
        EditText editHolders = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editHolders);
        EditText editBankName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editBankName);
        EditText editBranchName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editBranchName);
        EditText editAddress = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        EditText editIFSC = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editIFSC);
        EditText editMICR = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editMICR);
        EditText editBalance = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editBalance);
        EditText editRemarks = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editRemarks);


        }


  }

}
```

I have seen some previous post regarding this, but it didnt help me out, i tried some of them but `setContentView(R.layout.addaccount)` still had error in main.

Comment: What have you tried so we don't give you suggestions that don't work? The first thing to do is to go through every xml file, including `manifest.xml`, and make sure there are NO errors in any. Then clean the project by clicking "Project --> Clean..."

Comment: Can you post addaccount.xml

Comment: did you refactor anything or mess with the package? take a look at `R.java`: `Project Folder --> gen --> package name --> R.java` and see if there's anything wrong with it

Comment: Moderate your language please - you ask for help and start making demands, that's not a good start. Also your question is quite inadequate, as stated by the other commenters above. What did you try so far for instance? Did you clean up your project and such?

Comment: @halfer there are plenty of dupes. If you suggest one then I can close it instantly. On my phone right now so I don't want to search for one, atm

Comment: No worries. It's not my area @codeMagic, so I'll let my CV stand and see if someone wishes to follow it. I was just going to suggest "no mcve". I can't find any convincing dups for the error, but I don't know Android, so may be searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: @halfer yes I've cast a CV on it as unclear what you're asking as I believe since OP hasn't responded to any question or accepted any answers as the right answer, it's unclear how we can help solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the R class in your file? because I don't see it in your imports.

It should be something like this code:

```
import com.st.acccounts.R
```

or

```
import com.st.R
```

based on your application package.

or just hover over the R where the error occurs in your file and then click on import R.

After that try and clean - build your project again and i believe that it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in Eclipse IDE, maybe there are some errors in some XML files into res folder. Fix them and if problem persists do `Project -> Clean`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the `R.java` is existed, if not, you should find out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If Project > Clean doesn't work, try creating a new project and copying your code/resources over to the new project. That always solves the problem for me.